# WSDL2Java with CXF without annotations

Tags: java, annotations, cxf

I have an issue with CXF and have been looking in the doc but did not find how to do it, I am probably missing something, I am a beginner.
I am trying to generate stubs with CXF but can't find how to do it without the annotations.

From what I found on the doc, there is a frontend to use to do that, but when trying to use WSDL2java -fe "Simple", it can't find the frontend. I am sure I am missing a point here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "simple" frontend is really just for the "java first" use cases to develop/deploy services based on existing code that  may not have the annotations.

For wsdl first, we only really provide support for JAX-WS compatible interfaces, but with various databindings such as JAXB (the default), XMLBeans, SDO, JiBX, etc...

One of the main reasons is that the simple frontend cannot support all the various constructs in the WSDL like the the JAX-WS frontend can.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Daniel. Do you have an idea of how I should handle the problem to get the stubs without annotations? Using CXF is mandatory for me. Please excuse my english which is maybe not very good.